# How to put a list of word into a string quickly in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, text-editor

so I have a list of words like this

```
apple
banana
orange
```

So I want to make all of that into a separate string like this

```
'apple'
'banana'
'orange'
```

But I don't know the shortcut key for it as I saw people doing fast with not typing through each word which cost time and is inefficient.
I'm using pycharm btw

Comment: Smart Keys lets you select each word in turn and press the quote button to surround the word in quotes.  It won't do all at the same time though

Comment: @JeffUK but how to use smart keys, which shortcut key?